# App got rejected not following the iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

My app has downloadable content which I am keeping in Documents Directory. Which gets backed up on iCloud. So instead of setting "Do not backup" of all individual files can I put them under one directory in side Documents and set the "Do not backup" on that directory will that work? or do I have to set the flag on all individual files.

Comment: you may put them in the tmp directory instead of Documents directory .. or in cache ..

Comment: No I don't want to delete these files. These files are required for proper functioning of my app.

Comment: Downloadable content should be placed here: <Application_Home>/Library/Caches https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

Comment: I faced such rejection before .. then I made a directory under library .and then I downloaded the files there ..

Comment: Sorry for this, but I want to call your basic assumption into question. If the content is downloaded on demand, then it shouldn't matter if the cache is deleted. Conversely, if the content is required and not downloaded on demand, then it should be backup up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in your application before saving database to your document directory..

```
-(BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);

//  NSLog(@"Attributs : %d and Path : %@",result,URL);
    if (result != 0) { 

        NSLog(@"File Backup Attribute setting error");

    }

    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats fine but it does not answer my question :(

Comment: You can found from this link.  https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

Answer (score 0):

You can store all temporary files  or any other data which your program can genrate without help of users-(which is not user created data) at Library/tmp  folder - Library/tmp folder is not insider document folder, Its folder at the same level of Document directory.

You will not need to add donotbackup attribute to all files then.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. Read this [apple storage guideline](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)

In a nutshell for your app you want to follow guideline #2

> Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in
>   the /Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you
>   should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and
>   downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and
>   map applications.